# gcloud FileNotFoundError lib64

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, virtualenv, gcloud

Why do I get the following error when trying to deploy to Google Cloud App Engine?

```
gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/.../.../venv/lib64'
```

That directory exists on my local machine but the only reference to `lib64` in my code is in the .gitignore file. The Error seems to be connected to my environment, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

**Additional Details:**
The error only occurs when I try to deploy the code from one specific branch. I've deployed other branches from the developer that created this problem branch and haven't had any issues.

The Codebase is Python/Django. and this particular problem branch runs great on my local machine, It only gives me trouble when I try to deploy it to my dev server on Google App Engine.

The only thing that is reproducible in this error is this particular branch. I just unsure where to start looking for WHY this is happening.

Comment: Hi, it would be very helpful if you could add some reproduction steps or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows how is your issue being produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem:** Make sure your fellow devs have their virtual environment folder listed in their .gitignore file

Clue #1: This problem was only occurring on a single branch coming from another employee/dev

Clue #2: 'venv' is not the name of my own virtual environment

As soon as clue #2 dawned on me, I went looking and saw that my developer somehow committed this branch with his own `/venv/` folder. it should have been part of his .gitignore, but apparently wasn't. As soon as I deleted his erroneous '/venv/' file off of my dev server, then I was able to upload just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is given because your app is not able to locate the lib64 in the directory of virtual environment you set locally.

In [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#running_the_app_on_your_local_computer) to install the dependencies of your app, you need to to place it in a file called requirements.txt.

You can install all the dependencies your app has by going to your project directory and install them with pip command:

```
cd YOUR_PROJECT
pip install  -r requirements.txt
```

Also please have a look into the [Running Django in App Engine Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) .